# Parse XML in C# for configuration of Windows App

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, windows-runtime

I want to configure my app via a xml file, which will be parsed at the launch of my app. The xml file will have the following structure

```
<config>
  <modulea/>
  <moduleb/>
  <modulec/>
  <modulee/>
</config>
```

So as you can see I have an element called 'config' and within this element I have a list of modules (in this case a, b, c and e). So how can I parse this information, so that I know that I have to diaply the modules a, b, c and e and hide the module d?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't seem to be using the [System.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.configuration(v=vs.100).aspx) classes?

Comment: Well, I want to create a base application and some modules which uses the base app. So I've decided to use XML files, so I can decide which features should be activated in this context.

Comment: Is it a Windows Store app or a Windows Desktop app?

Comment: I mean if it's WinRT you are using it's probably a store app and so System.Configuration is not available.

Comment: It is a Windows Store app.

Answer (score 0):

Your three best bets would be to either use `Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument` and manually build everything or use serialization based on `System.Runtime.Serialization` classes where you'd mark your class and properties with attributes such as `DataContract` and `DataMember` and then serialize/deserialize the file as in [this article](http://irisclasson.com/2012/07/11/example-metro-app-winrt-serializing-and-deseralizing-objects-using-xmlserializer-to-storagefile-and-localfolder-using-generics-and-asyncawait-threading/) for example. You can also use manual XML manipulation using Linq with `System.Linq.XML`'s `XDocument` as in [this article](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/how-to-read-xml-files-in-windows-8---winrt).